# Changing the Adyen reference after a successful payment

Tags: reference, adyen

So, I have a bit of an awkward situation - We are using Adyen drop-in for an SFCC Headless app, we are doing a /session request and the reference we are providing is the basket UUID.
The problem arrives when the payment is authorized (all as expected) and the adyen hook is submitted to the SFCC environment, at that point an Adyen process job (that we cannot modify - as we are trying to build a reuseable plug and play app that connects to SFCC) picks up the notification and tries to match an order that is equal to that reference. The orderID however is completely different - so what I am looking to achieve is - is there a way to update the reference of a payment that has been authorized OR if this is not possible - where exactly in the drop-in flow can I change the reference from being a basket UUID to an order ID.
The problem with doing the latter however seems to be that - the only actually necessary call for the drop-in flow is /sessions (which we NEED to do way before orders are created due to actually needing it to render the payment fields).

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Tried looking through the docs, but cannot seem to find anything useful on this matter.

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of using the sessions flow. Once the merchant reference is set it cannot be updated.

Here are the possible approaches:

1. Use the [Advanced flow](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/additional-use-cases/advanced-flow-integration/?platform=Web&integration=Drop-in&version=5.55.1) instead of Adyen sessions.
2. Try to generate the order number before creating the session and set that as a merchant reference that comes from demandware class OrderMgr.

Hope this helps.

[image]